# how to implement in app purchase for app on play store in Flutter and Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-services

I am developing app which uses ticket system and users can buy consumable tickets to spend and The ticket data should be saved in firebase firestore into user document so how to implement it?

can I use 3rd party packages like Razorpay or Square ?but by Playstore rules the transaction should be via google play billing api as they take 30% cut!?

all I want to do is when user buy some tickets and transaction is completed then their ticket quantity in firebase firestore should increase so that when the use it I can decrement that value from Firestore.

Comment: This is a bit too vague regarding the implementation if you could be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

In case when you sell real tickets for some events, you can use third-party acquiring like Stripe or Square and avoid 30% Google commission.
But if you are selling virtual goods or services (including some virtual tickets in your app) you must use Google in-app purchases. Otherwise, your app might be removed from the store.
You can check our service, which makes it easy to implement in-app purchases and subscriptions. It provides simple methods so you don't have to deal with Google Billing or Apple Storekit directly.
Here is a [quick start guide](http://documentation.qonversion.io/docs/quickstart)